# why this method is not giving me the subnet mask in android

Tags: java, android, subnet

I have a method that gets the subnet mask using android shell command. I tested on adb and works; however, I just put it in a method and I can get the output displayed on the android monitor console. If there's an easier way please advise. Thanks. By the way I'm running this in main activity thread (no Asynctask)

```
/*
    * method to return private subnet mask
    */
    public String getPrivateSubnet() {

        String output = "";
        final String SUBNET_CMD = "/system/bin/ifconfig wlan0 | find \"Mask\"";
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(SUBNET_CMD);
//            p.wait();
            Log.v("SUBNET OUTPUT", p.toString());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.v("SUBNET", inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("SUBNET", output);
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use ifconfig use:

```
ifconfig wlan0 |  awk '/netmask/{print $4}'
```

EDIT: I did some really quick coding of myself to find this one. Yes the Java API lets you use the NetworkInterface class to get the ipv4 subnetmask of an interface. I made a piece of code that may be helpful for you. This code gives you the CIDR value of each interface (for example: 24 would be 255.255.255.0). See more on this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, SocketException {

            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

            while (networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = networkInterfaces.nextElement();
                try {
                    for (InterfaceAddress address : networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()) {
                        System.out.println(address.getNetworkPrefixLength());
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've searched for other ways but it is so cumbersome to get the subnet mask of ipv4. ipv6 I can get it using NetworInterface class, but it will not give me ipv4. That's why I'm using this method

Comment: this method of using ipconfig wlan is not reliable across android phones. The output varies from phone to phone. Is there a way to get subnet mask of ipv4 using java api

Comment: This is the answer.  Thx